# Bazel: how to override git_repository commit for integration testing?

Tags: bazel

I'd like to add an integration test to [`rules_k8s`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_k8s) that allows an updated commit SHA to be passed in at the command-line to override the default commit hash of `rules_docker` in the [`WORKSPACE`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_k8s/blob/master/WORKSPACE#L16:L20). The motivation is to have a CI test that checks if `rules_docker` contains a regression that effects `rules_k8s`.

For `rules_scala`, I did something similar [via `--override_repository`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_scala/blob/8117089e8969861b1774485cb49ab95b54c2b9c9/test_intellij_aspect.sh#L23), but that seems more complex than should be needed for this case.

Comment: I think that feature doesn’t exist. Only the one you link to. Consider opening a FR over on Bazel repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible at the moment, would you mind opening a feature request at https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel?

Comment: Thanks, mhlopko and ittaiz. I created this issue: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/4993.